# Removing quotes in flask output

Tags: python, flask, web-development-server

basically i have been using flask to display account info and have decided to try and import a whole element into flask being

```
('<img src="'+gamerpic+'" width="50px" height="50px">')
```

but for some reason when flask loads it it adds quotations around the element making it a text

image of the problem

[image: 1]

heres my code

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    try: get_gamertag(),
    except: pass    
    with open('dataparse.txt') as f:
        gamertag = f.read()
    with open('dataparse1.txt') as f:
        gamerpic = f.read()
    return render_template('pages/index.html', gamertag=gamertag, gamerpic=gamerpic)
```

anyone know how to remove the quotation marks

i explained everything above /\

Comment: Where is `('<img src="'+gamerpic+'" width="50px" height="50px">')` in the code you posted? If that's in `dataparse.txt`, it won't be executed as Python code, you're just reading it as literal text and putting that into the web page.

Answer (score -1):

This caused because templates are protected to unnecessary code from values. You should try `autoescape false` block which disables autoescape:

```
{% autoescape false %}
    <p>{{ gamertag }}</p>
{% endautoescape %}

{% autoescape false %}
    <p>{{ gamerpic }}</p>
{% endautoescape %}
```

This should render your value even as html code